# Calling action method when time expires

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In one model class I have member DateTime TimeExpired. How to automatically call some action method when time expires? When time expires I need to do some calculations and store them in database. e.q. that time period can be day long, month long etc.

Comment: Do you want to call javascript code when .net time class property expire?

Comment: You can do timer jobs from within a Model class. Models are for relaying data from the Action method to the View. They only exist for a short duration while the page is rendered to HTML, not the entire time the user is on the page.

Comment: "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking."

Comment: If I can call action method from that javascript code then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime TimeExpired
```

is not a good way to go with JavaScript.

1) I hope this date is set with Utc, like:

```
model.TimeExpired = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10);
```

Otherwise you'll have problems in client side. I highly recommend to get rid of this code and rewrite it to

```
DateTimeOffset TimeExpiredUtc
```

2) When you have UTC datetime on the client, you can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library to parse the time and set timeout:

```
// get number of milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC
var now = moment().utc().valueOf();
// parse string object and get number of milliseconds
var when = moment(TimeExpiredUtc).valueOf();

// calculate the difference
var timeout = when - now;
setTimeout(function() {
    // place your ajax code to call asp.net mvc action here
}, timeout);
```

I'm not sure that code above is correct, but you got the point.

3) Keep in mind that this method won't be called if client will close a tab. I hope it's okay for you. Because if it's not, you need completely different approach.

Comment: It is good advice, but as I waited a bit long for answer, I found solution for my problem without using javascript.